# Type based on the static propreties of interfaces

Tags: typescript

I have multiple interfaces that all has a propriety called `id` and this is an unique static string for each of these interfaces.

For example:

```
interface Cat{
  id: 'cat',
  furColor: string,
  likeMice: boolean,
}

interface Dog {
  id: 'dog',
  watchDogSkillLevel: number
}
```

Then I have another interface that has a proprety to needs to be one of the id of the above interfaces.
I know I can use `string` but I want to use TypeScript type checking if possible.

```
interface Toy {
  forAnimal: string, // <- how to restrict this to id of either Dog or Cat
}
```

I also know I can simply put `forAnimal:'cat' | 'dog'`  but If I have 100 interfaces for the animal, will I have to write them one by one ? Is there a better way ?

Comment: In words, how would you describe this type other than "one of these 100 specific strings?" If you were looking at the code (forget about TypeScript), what rule would you use so *you* would know if the string "kangaroo" were valid for `forAnimal`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an [enum](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) to define all possible animals. You have to specify them all once and then you can use it in both scenarios.

For example like this:

```
enum Animal {
   cat = 'cat',
   dog = 'dog'
}

interface Cat{
  id: Animal.cat,
  furColor: string,
  likeMice: boolean,
}

interface Dog {
  id: Animal.dog,
  watchDogSkillLevel: number
}

interface Toy {
  forAnimal: Animal // can be dog or cat
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use type checking, you're going to need to list to Typescript either which animals are allowed or which strings are allowed; otherwise Typescript will not be able to definitively tell you that unexpected values (`jackalope` and `unicorn`) are not allowed. As in AlesD's answer, you could do this by [listing strings as an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60403950/1426891). The other strategy is to list the possible animal interfaces as a type union and letting Typescript infer the possible strings.

```js
type Animal = Cat | Dog;
type AnimalId = Animal["id"];

interface Toy {
  forAnimal: AnimalId,
}
```

This allows you to define the `id`s within the interfaces and only define the union type once; if you have a unique static string to determine the types, I expect you have one already. This is also enough for Typescript to infer the type based on the string (as a ["discriminated union"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions)):

```js
function processAnimal(animal: Animal) {
    if (animal.id === "cat") {
        animal.likeMice = true;
    } else {
        animal.watchDogSkillLevel = 9001;
    }
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=25&ssc=2&pln=19&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzAbwFDOcAEwC5kByBDUgGl2RgFcpUB7AG2ahIGcwpQBzGnlbAA1hACywJCQBGzNhDggaAX2zZQkWIhQARZv2Q48hEqQKHqtAO4YEACwP8AyqOCtWAGQgA3CKwkIPQAtrLQ2OrYYACeAA4oAIIgwCFwrMgAvGgYyAA+yM4A3NHxSSlprACSBFnIyanpANoARIQtALolmuDQ8EjIACrMMca0MBwNlSRT6TVqGgwgCGDAzCDIcVDMSFxcs6wAFMqNgfUV6QCUY3imMMjHF6wAdIRZmdktFGAt1ya3AJOlWeInEUgG2V49AgJQBqmQAS4KH+ALwQPSzzsYEczjcHm8fgCdQAnAAGUkARlht3UqiAA)